# Configurar câmera para jogos 2D para android

Tags: unity3d

Fiz um jogo teste para aparelhos com Android.

Entretanto ao testar em um aparelho, o jogo ficou todo distorcido, espremido na tela.

No computador, ao testar o jogo fiz um print da largura do ecrã e devolveu 1440 que é exatamente a largura do aparelho que estou a testar, um Samsung Note 4.

Eu sei que esse 1440 no celular não é o mesmo para o pc, há diferenças na densidade, porém não sei  como resolver esse problema.

Como funciona a câmera no Unity3D e como resolve o problema para diferentes resoluções/densidades?

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**:

Veja uma imagem de como fica o jogo pelo simulador do Unity: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E outra imagem de como fica em um aparelho android depois de fazer build e run:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não alterei a câmera, que está com os seguintes valores: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se ficou espremido na tela, tem a ver com a razão de aspecto (*aspect ratio*) da câmera. Você está alterando o valor de [`Camera.aspect`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-aspect.html)? Alguns screenshots (tanto do desktop como do dispositivo móvel) podem ser úteis na questão.

Comment: Dica: http://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.ie/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html

Comment: @LuizVieira alterei a pergunta e adicionei as imagens de como fica em cada ecrã. Obrigado.

Comment: E como essa imagem do castelo está sendo exibida? É um objeto de GUI, um plano com textura, ou o que? A imagem rotaciona no celular (quando você coloca o dispositivo na horizontal)?

Comment: @LuizVieira a imagem é um sprite com rigidbody2D e box collider2D. A imagem não rotaciona no celular porque configurei o game para rodar em portrait.

Comment: Você fez o build e instalou o apk num dispositivo android, ou está usando o Unity Remote? Esta segunda imagem é muito comum quando se usa o Unity remote, mas geralmente é melhor usar ele para testar o input do dispositivo. Se não, remova esta imagem, e tende usar uma das ferramentas do unity para adicionar um 3d, ou até 2D, mas não importe imagens. Só para ver se isso só acontece com coisas importadas, sei que para iPhone ele costuma converter a imagem e estragar ela. E por ultimo, as configurações do teu projeto: `edit>project settings > player ` além do player tem outros, mas ali é onde

Comment: ..tem as configurações da build. Desculpe por não poder ajudar além, estou atualizando para o windows 10, e tá dando um trabalhão deixar do jeito que eu gosto.

Comment: @Nils Eu estou a fazer build e run diretamente para um dispositivo android, não estou a usar o Unity Remote. A imagem é um sprite que adicionei aos assets e depois arrastei para a área de trabalho do Unity e adicionei um rigidbody2D e boxcolider2D.

Comment: Certo, vc conseguiu adicionar um item do próprio Unity para ver como ele fica?
Olhou o caminho que te mandei para ver as configurações como o `aspect-ratio`? Ou talvez marcar o `Maximize on Play`
Não se esqueça que também pode ser o padrão de importação da imagem. Mas eu preciso que você realize os testes que passei para poder filtrar o que se trata.

Comment: @Nils Então, eu abri o player settings mas não havia nada relacionado a "aspect-ratio" nem "maximize on play". Eu estou usando a última versão do unity. Em relação ao teste, você diz para adicionar um item do próprio unity, ou seja, adicionar um quadrado e ver se fica distorcido no celular? Sou novo no Unity, ainda estou a ver alguns conceitos.

Comment: No android quer que se veja com o dispositivo ao alto ou de lado ??
Colocou o modo preview para andoid também ? e as Build Settings colocou o modo que queria visualizar o que criou ?
Espero conseguir ajudar.